# CSS responsive layout with

Tags: css

I'm having trouble designing a responsive website. Up until now I've always worked with a fixed width of 1024px. By doing so, I've avoided annoying responsive designs. But it's time to change!

First of all, <s>I'd like my page to be 1024px wide maximum, but when the page get's narrowed the content needs to be narrowed as well. Issue I'm currently having is that using `max-width` messes up the `margin:auto;` since the page needs to be centered.</s>

On my page I'd like a left-column that contains a box, and to the right of that would be different boxes. The whole thing should be centered in the page, but when using `margin:auto;` on the boxes, I can't add a margin so they don't press against each other. I also can't find a way to get the left box on the left and avoid other boxes displaying underneath it.
I've made some mockups of what the page should look like:
*Note: header doesn't need to be 1024px wide anymore*

[image: Full page]

Here you can see the viewport (orange border) and lay-out. The green block should take up the whole height on that side of the page, so the other blocks won't go under it. When the page get's narrowed, it should look like this:

[image: Narrow page]

You can see the elements should still be centered on the page, and again the green block should be to the left of the other blocks having a full page height.

Extra: In case this is less an effort than I predicted (I've been messing around for days), the green box should, when scrolled, stay on the page as in the following image:[image: Scrolled full page]

**Here's the current code:** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5pWw/3/)

I know it's a lot of images and a wall of text, but I have no idea how to get started on this...

Comment: U want to have a responsive design but you want max-width 1024px? :| I understand that it's popular to make it responsive for mobile phones. But u should think about people with 24 inch monitors too! :D

Comment: And your code so far ?

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you posted the code for an example page (with CSS in `style` tags in the head). It looks like your header has a fixed width, which would defeat the purpose of responsive design.

Comment: Code included in jsfiddle. And perhaps the 1024px isn't the best idea then indeed... But a whole page seems so wide, no? Without the 1024px width is good as well then!

Comment: Why are you styling the divs inside the HTML code while u can just have it in CSS? Btw you are setting the container width 1024.. that's kinda fixed width.. nothing responsive there :(

Comment: @Ms.Nobody: I had it fully in the css, but then started fumbling around with it and found it easier inline, here's it in the css: http://jsfiddle.net/G5pWw/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got most of what you wanted. Is that enough for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/wallysalami/T9k74/6/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class='topbox'></div>
    <table id='boxes-table'>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id='leftbox' class='static-top-position'></div>
                </td>
                <td class='boxes-column'>
                    <div class='box'></div>
                    <div class='box'></div>
                    <div class='box'></div>
                    <div class='box'></div>
                    <div class='box'></div>
                    <div class='box'></div>
                    <div class='box'></div>
                    <div class='box'></div>
                    <div class='box'></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    text-align: center;
}

.fixed-top-position
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}

.static-top-position
{
    position: static;
}

.topbox
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 998px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

.box
{
    height:300px;
    width:228px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 5px;
}

#leftbox
{
    height:300px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 10px 30px 0px 10px;
}

#boxes-table
{
    max-width: 998px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto 0px;
}

#boxes-table > tbody> tr > td
{
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    var tableTopPosition = $( '#boxes-table' ).offset( ).top - $( window ).scrollTop( );
    var magicNumber = 5;

    var leftbox = $( '#leftbox' );
    var leftboxClass = leftbox.attr( 'class' );
    var topPosition = leftbox.top;

    if ( tableTopPosition < magicNumber && leftboxClass == 'static-top-position' )
    {
        leftbox.attr( 'class', 'fixed-top-position' );
    } else if ( tableTopPosition > magicNumber && leftboxClass == 'fixed-top-position' )
    {
        leftbox.attr( 'class', 'static-top-position' );
    }
});
```

Comment: A table-based layout to display a bunch of divs? I think my eyes are bleeding... :)

Comment: I've learnt after much pain that tables are a safe way to position elements and avoid crazy behaviors when the window and/or elements resize. Since I don't know what he will do with those squares, better safe than sorry.

Comment: Sure, I was just joking. However, it is a bit ironic that this question is aboout responsive CSS and you offer table layout that would not really be "responsive" in the traditional sense (like elements displaying below others in smaller devices yet side-by-side on larger devices).

Answer (score 1):

OK, you will have to treat the left box as if it were in a column  to stop any wrapping underneath as the easiest option.
As for the other boxes and space between them just use css3 ***box-sizing:border-box;*** and add padding. A good example is here http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm appearing to be failing miserably in both things. http://jsfiddle.net/G5pWw/15/

Comment: OK, I see the issue. Put the floated right div in the HTML before the left div. Then add your width to the #right column say 700px. And you will see 2 boxes of white on the right. This div of #right has to be the @media query you put in to the various sizes you choose at viewport width - ie 456px on #right would show 2, 684px on #right would show 3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a lot of time to spend on this but this should point you in the right direction if nothing else.

http://jsfiddle.net/G5pWw/17/

I added position: fixed to lock in the left box while you scroll and floated it left.  I also adjusted the width to 30% and max-width 200px for responsive design.

```
#leftbox {
position: fixed;
float:left;
height:300px;
width: 30%;
max-width:200px;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

I added a container to hold all the boxes on the right side. I made the width 70%, you can set a max width if you want.  I floated the container right.

```
#box_container {
float: right;
width: 70%;
}
```

All in all this keeps your left box locked in on the left even when you scroll and moves around your right boxes depending on screen width.  You will need to play with padding and such but this should work.  Hope this helps!  If you have any questions I will try to respond fairly quickly.